# How to get unstripped .so from externalNativeBuild and cmake with gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, cmake, crashlytics-android

im trying to get Crashlytics NDK reporting working with my **.cpp** code built using **Android studio**, **gradle** and **cmake** like so (no custom stuff)

```
externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
```

Crashlytics NDK wants the paths to stripped and unstripped binaries. The stripped one is by default in "build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj", however I cant find the unstripped one.

Then I looked at the console output while building and it contained task

```
:app:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug
```

*So I presume the unstripped is not being built / kept. Any way to make it save the unstripped .so? Thanks*

Comment: Are the libs in that directory the only ones you can find? I thought cmake/gradle functioned the way ndk-build does here: we build with debug info and make a separate stripped copy for the APK. Based on my reading of these two bugs, we definitely build with debug info: https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/243 https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=229391

Comment: should I look for any other .so file? (im ndk noob)

Comment: ok I found 2 more folders where some .sos are, \app\build\intermediates\transforms\stripDebugSymbol\debug\folders\2000\1f\main\lib\armeabi-v7a\libnative-lib.so

\app\build\intermediates\transforms\mergeJniLibs\debug\folders\2000\1f\main\lib\armeabi-v7a\libnative-lib.so

and other abi variants + they contain all other .so from 3rd party dependencies like realm etc...so that means that these are the stripped ones and the "build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj" are with debug info?

Comment: Okay it works! "build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj" for with debug info, "build/intermediates/transforms/stripDebugSymbol/release/folders/2000/1f/main/lib" for stripped .so ... although, the folders/2000/1f/ in path seems sketchy, is it ment to be referenced or is it some cache or something?